# Images in some <li> at wordpress navigation

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, navigation

Can i put images in navigation in wordpress
I want some of `<li>` to be with text ex: Home and some of them to be images Ex:facebook's logo for `<li>` named Facebook.

Is there any possible way to catch the text content of the li in wordpress
with php or JS may be ??

It is easy to catch it if the navigation is statically written but in WP it is dynamically loaded and looks something like this :

```
<?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme-location' => 'nav',
            'container' => 'nav'
        ));

        ?>
```

Thanks ( :

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what do you exactly want. What do you mean with `<li> named Facebook`?

Comment: It's kind of a hack, but you can write a WP filter to look for a menu item containing a link that directs to twitter, facebook, etc. and replace the contents with an image. It forces you to do some hard-coding, but it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and probably the best way to do is is this:

Add a CSS class to the menu item you want to include an image. You can add these CSS classes from the default Worpress Admin under `Appeareance -> Menus`

If you open that page you can click the down arrow on the menu item you want to add a class to. Then a input field `CSS Classes (optional)` appears. Enter a usefull CSS class name (like `facebook-image`) here

If you don't see that option; check the settings under `Screen options` (top right on the menus page)